# Ugly look of progress bar in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

What happened to the progress bar in the Stack Exchange Android app? Why is it not a perfectly round shape?

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are just drunk.

Comment: @hims056 developers or progress bar itself? :P lol

Comment: @PareshMayani Is this bug ?

Comment: Actually I find this pretty :D

Comment: Thats not ugly, a kind of [3-D loader](http://preloaders.net/en/3d) which is looking good.

Comment: @Praveen yes I know developers has tried to animate it, but then why they have applied to this only? Whatever it is, it looks ugly in many devices.

Comment: I don't have this on my version.  Do yet have more details?

Comment: People is still down voting even though Kasra has given a valid reason below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is happening because the `ProgressBar` has padding set only on the top and bottom, skewing it depending on how your phone's native UI was displaying them. I changed it from being padding to margins, which should fix this issue. Look for it in 1.0.22.